# Passing a member function as an argument

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have this public method inside a class:

```
uli returnSum()
{
    for_each(i, j, doSum);
    return this->sum;
}
```

`void doSum(short int y)` is a private method of the very same class. How would I pass it as an argument to for_each?

Using the syntax above I'm getting `error: must
use .* or ->* to call pointer-to-member function in __f (...)'`. Neither is `this->*doSum` working.

I read something about creating a pointer towards that member function and passing it as an argument but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate.  There are too many similar questions already on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use std::bind, like this

```
std::for_each(i, j, std::bind(&MyClass::doSum, this));
```

Comment: It seems my compiler doesn't know about any "bind" declared within the std namespace.

Comment: Did you #include <functional>?

Comment: Yeah, still getting "error: `bind' undeclared in namespace 'std'" though.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Does it implement C++11's stdlib? You could also use Boost's libraries...

Comment: Just picked up on that, it lacks C++11's stuff, that's why it doesn't recognize bind as part of the std namespace. Going to try it in MSVC 2012.

Comment: In GCC or Intel compiler you can turn on C++0x support with `-std=c++0x` option.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
  public:
    int fun1(int x) { return x+1; }
};

typedef int (Test::*PtrType)(int);

void call(Test& self, PtrType prt) {
    cout << (self.*ptr)(2) << endl;
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    call(t, &Test::fun1);
    return 0;
}
```

The line `typedef int (Test::*PtrType)(int);` defines simple name for the type to the class method. The parenthesis around `(Test::*PtrType)` are important; `PtrType` is the new defined type (Although you could do without the typedef, and put the whole signature in the `call` function arguments, such approach is strongly discouraged).

The expression `(self.*ptr)(2)` calls the method pointed by your pointer `ptr`, passing 2 as its argument. Again the key point is putting parenthesis around `(self.*ptr)`.

The last point to remember is that you cannot skip `&` when setting the value of the pointer (`&Test::fun1`), even as it is possible with regular function.

You can make your code a little neater, if you use templates:

```
template <typename PtrT>
void call(Test& self, PtrT ptr) {
    cout << (self.*ptr)(2) << endl;
}
```

No typedef is necessary in such case, however, you must still remember about parenthesis in the invocation.

If you are compiling with the new C++0x standard, you can use `std::function` or `std::bind`.